# Raise two errors at the same time

Tags: python

Is there any way to raise two errors at the same time by using try and except?
For example,  `ValueError` and `KeyError`.

How do I do that?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Do you mean 'raise' or 'catch'?

Comment: You can *catch* two exceptions at once as below, either handling them both the same or handling them each differently.  That way you will be prepared no matter which exception is raised.  But you cannot raise two errors at once, unless you make a subclass of two errors in which case that error will be caught by an except for either parent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try :
    pass
except (ValueError,KeyError):
    pass
```

read more about [Handling exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: For clarification: The question asked originally how to catch two errors, not how to raise them. That's why this answer is the accepted one.

Comment: That's not what the page history says.

Answer (score 159):

The question asks how to **RAISE** multiple errors not catch multiple errors.

Strictly speaking you can't raise multiple exceptions but you could raise an object that contains multiple exceptions.

```
raise Exception(
    [
        Exception("bad"),
        Exception("really bad"),
        Exception("really really bad"),
    ]
)
```

**Question**: Why would you ever want to do this?
**Answer**: In a loop when you want to raise an error but process the loop to completion.

For example when unit-testing with `unittest2` you might want to raise an exception and keep processing then raise all of the errors at the end.  This way you can see all of the errors at once.

```
def test_me(self):
    
    errors = []
    
    for modulation in self.modulations:
        logging.info('Testing modulation = {modulation}'.format(**locals()))

        self.digitalModulation().set('value', modulation)
        reply = self.getReply()
   
        try: 
            self._test_nodeValue(reply, self.digitalModulation())
        except Exception as e:
            errors.append(e)
            
    if errors:
        raise Exception(errors)
```

**Python 3.11**

Starting with 3.11 you can use [ExceptionGroup](https://realpython.com/python311-exception-groups/#group-exceptions-with-exceptiongroup) to raise multiple exceptions.

```
raise ExceptionGroup("this was bad",
    [
        Exception("bad"),
        Exception("really bad"),
        Exception("really really bad"),
    ]
)
```

Comment: You seem to be the only person who read the question correctly.

Comment: @prooffreader the question was originally asking something different before someone else edited it. As you can see, the downvoted question is the accepted one, so it was actually answering the question. Take a look at the history of the question.

Comment: @soerface the history of the question doesn't support your claim... There is only one edit indeed of someone else which is only minor formatting and didn't change the meaning of the question. Unless there was an edit in the first 2 minutes of the question (that is not logged in the history)...

Comment: Python 3.11 introduces exception groups. So the last line in the example would be:
`raise ExceptionGroup("test_me exceptions: ", errors)`

Comment: regarding the "why would you", I think it's fairly obvious. Exceptions are just another way of providing feedback, having more feedback before stopping execution makes a lot of sense. In my case I will check the presence of multiple dependencies of different types, if I am made aware of one missing dependency at a time, it would take me forever to find and fix them all.

Answer (score 6):

You could raise an error which inherits from both `ValueError` and `KeyError`. It would get caught by a catch block for either.

```
class MyError(ValueError, KeyError):
    ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can handle more than one error, either using

```
try:
    # your code here
except (ValueError, KeyError) as e:
    # catch it, the exception is accessable via the variable e
```

Or, directly add two "ways" of handling different errors:

```
try:
    # your code here
except ValueError as e:
    # catch it, the exception is accessable via the variable e
except KeyError as e:
    # catch it, the exception is accessable via the variable e
```

You may also leave out the "e" variable.

Checkout the documentation: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: For clarification: The question asked originally how to catch two errors, not how to raise them. That's why this answer exists and that's also why the downvoted question is the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from @shrewmouse still requires to choose an exception class to wrap the caught exceptions.

- Following solution uses [Exception Chaining](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/#id36) via `finally` to execute code after one exception occurs
- We **don't need to know beforehand, what exceptions occur**
- Note that **only the first exception** that occurs can be detected from the caller via `except`

  - if this is a problem, use @Collin's [solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12826388/5864166) to inherit from all collected exceptions
- You'll see the exceptions separated by:
  "`During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`"

```py
def raise_multiple(errors):
    if not errors:  # list emptied, recursion ends
        return
    try:
        raise errors.pop()  # pop removes list entries
    finally:
        raise_multiple(errors)  # recursion
```

---

If you have a **task that needs to be done for each element of a list**, you don't need to collect the Exceptions beforehand. Here's an example for multiple file deletion with multiple error reporting:

```py
def delete_multiple(files):
    if not files:
        return
    try:
        os.remove(files.pop())
    finally:
        delete_multiple(files)
```

---

PS:
Tested with Python 3.8.5
To print full traceback per exception have a look at [traceback.print_exc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc)
The original question is answered since years. But as this page is the top search result for "python raise multiple" I share my approach to fill an (IMHO relevant) gap in the solution spectrum.

Comment: My solution does not require the try loop to know anything about the caught exception. The process raising the exception, is the one that deals with creating an object holding multiple exceptions.

Comment: Choosing "Exception" as the wrapping exception class is an unnecessary definition. In effect, your approach always throws this class, for example: Exception: [TypeError(...), TypeError(...)]. Nice and short, but the printed trace doesn't indicate paths of the errors that occurred, but instead, the line where "Exception(errors)" was defined.

My solution does not define a wrapping class, so one can catch the (first/last) actually occurred exception from outside. This can be used to automatically take appropriate measures towards solving the problem. So I think it is a useful addition.

Comment: This is pretty clever and retains the exception formatting. I am using this, only I set it to `errors.pop(0)` to get them in order of execution.

Comment: I should also add, with this method, there's no need for the traceback module, you get the full exception including traceback, nicely wrapped up at the end, and as mentioned, in order if you `pop(0)`. Also, if you use a closure, you don't need to pass it the errors, as the errors variable is in scope.

Answer (score -1):

You can **Raise** more than one exception like this:

```py
try:
    i = 0
    j = 1 / i
except ZeroDivisionError:
    try:
        i = 'j'
        j = 4 + i
    except TypeError:
        raise ValueError
```

**NOTE:** it may be that only the ValueError is raised but this error message seems right:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 3, in <module>
    j = 1 / i
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 7, in <module>
    j = 4 + i
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 9, in <module>
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```