# Possible to raise two types of errors?

Tags: python, exception, raiserror

So I'm experimenting making my own program. I have the user input a string and an integer (name, age).

I want to raise a Value Error if the age is under 1 (if age > 1:) I did that. But I'm not sure what to do if the name is not a string. Is it a TypeError and can two types of errors be raised at the same time? If so how?

Probably got some terminology wrong but having trouble thinking right now.

Here's the code:

```
# This program asks name how old you are and makes exceptions to check and see if 
there are errors

def hogwarts_express (name, age):

    if age < 1:

        raise ValueError ("Error: Apparently you don't exist.  Please pick a number older 
than 0!")

    if int (age) >= 10:
        print ("Hello {}!  Welcome to the Hogwarts Express, your old enough to go now.  
Here 's your ticket!".format(name))
    else:
        print ("Sorry {} you're not old enough to board the express.".format(name))
try:
    your_name = input("What's your name?  ")
    age = int(input("How old might you be?  "))
    together = hogwarts_express (your_name, age)

except ValueError as err:
    print ("That's not a valid value.  Please input something else.")
    print ("{}".format(err))

else:
    print (together)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raise two errors at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826291/raise-two-errors-at-the-same-time)

Comment: One exception is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really no need to raise two exceptions simultaneously. It's fine to raise the first error you detect. Yes, a `TypeError` is appropriate if you expected a string but got something else. You can do the check and raise the `TypeError` either before or after the `ValueError`. You can catch multiple exception types in the same `try` statement by adding more `except` clauses.

Another option is to use an `assert` statement to validate all the arguments. An assertion indicates that a violation is a bug in the program, and you don't want to recover by using a `try` statement.

I should mention that it is possible to *chain* exceptions in Python (using the `raise ... from ...` syntax), but this used when translating from one exception type to another or for when one exception causes another, which does not seem to apply to this case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to throw all the exceptions at once, that's just pointless and serves no other purpose than to properly confuse the user. Either throw one specific exception per error found, or throw a general exception with a message that contains all the errors found.