# How show val er

Tags: python, django

Need some help with the if statements and Vaidation errors.

Right now I have this function:

```
def validate(self, validated_data):
    if self.partial:
        validated_data = self.fill_data(self.instance, validated_data)
    if not validated_data['brand'].sunny_account.first():
        raise ValidationError('This brand not Sunny')
    validated_data['calculate'] = Account.NEW
    return validated_data
```

Need to add another if statement:

```
if not validated_data['brand'].moon_account.first():
        raise ValidationError('This brand not Moon')
```

If I add another if not statement in this function it's not going to the second one if not and raising the first Validation error.
I would like that this function checking all if's and raising Validation error for the each case.

Comment: Can you clarify - do you want multiple errors raised in certain conditions? If so check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826291/raise-two-errors-at-the-same-time).

Comment: if the first is valid raise error, but check also the second one, if it's also valid raise error, if not - return validated data

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you want both the Moon and Sunny errors to be raised. However, this cannot happen: if the first is raised, then the second will never be reached. If the first is not raised, only then can the second be raised. But both can't be raised at the same time.

Comment: I would like if the first will raise it need to check the second one , if its also is valid - raise this too, if not return valid data

Comment: You can't strictly speaking raise two exceptions simultaneously, Charlie is right.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, do it in a loop:

```
def validate(self, validated_data):
    if self.partial:
        validated_data = self.fill_data(self.instance, validated_data)

    validations = [
        (
            validated_data['brand'].sunny_account.first(), 
            'This brand does not have Sunny enabled'
        ),
        (
            validated_data['brand'].moon_account.first(), 
            'This brand does not have Moon enabled'
        ),
    ]
    
    # Validate
    err_msg = ""
    for cond, msg in validations:
        if not cond:
            # Has error, add the error message
            err_msg = err_msg + msg

    if err_msg:
        # Error message is not empty --> there is an error
        raise ValidationError(err_msg)
    validated_data['calculate'] = Account.NEW
    return validated_data
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unusual to want to do this, and handling your exceptions elsewhere might be tricky, but you could raise an Exception of Exceptions something like this:

```py
def my_test(thing):
   errors = []
   if thing != 1:
      errors.append(ValidationError('thing 1'))
   if thing != 2:
      errors.append(ValidationError('thing 2'))
   if errors:
      Raise(ValidationError(errors))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't `raise` two exceptions at once, but you can define your own `Exception` subclass that incorporates arbitrary data.  For example, you could store a list of multiple error messages:

```
class ValidationError(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._why: list[str] = []

    def __bool__(self) -> bool:
        return bool(self._why)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "\n".join(self._why)

    def add(self, why: str) -> None:
        self._why.append(why)
```

and then accumulate multiple messages before deciding to raise:

```
    err = ValidationError()
    if not validated_data['brand'].sunny_account.first():
        err.add('This brand does not have Sunny enabled')
    if not validated_data['brand'].moon_account.first():
        err.add('This brand does not have Moon enabled')
    if err:
        raise err
```